# How to Handle Custom Lambda Errors in API Gateway Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

In my app i want handle the custom errors like 500,403,201,400 errors, i have tried in nodejs its working fine but i am working with python so i did'nt find any solution in python to handle the http status codes, so is there any way to handle them that helps me a lot.

```
var myErrorObj = {
    status : 500,
    errorType : "InternalServerError",
    httpStatus : 233,
    requestId : context.awsRequestId,
    trace : {
        "function": "abc()",
        "line": 123,
        "file": "abc.js"
    }
};
const responseInvoke = (eventData) => {
    return lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'test777',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({"eventData":event}) // pass param
    }).promise();
};

responseInvoke(event)
.then(res => {
    console.log('*** response *** ', res);
    const parsedRes = JSON.parse(res.Payload);
    if(parsedRes.status === 'success') {
        callback(null, res.Payload);
    } else {
        context.fail(JSON.stringify(myErrorObj));
    }
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    context.fail(JSON.stringify(myErrorObj));
});
```

here is the code which i have invoked from python lambda to nodejs lambda in python lambda i am returning success (or) fail messages to nodejs lambda based on the message i am sending the response to API gateway.